# Deploy Asp.net mvc in linux

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux

Currently i am doing a project in ASP .net MVC5 web application and it need to deploy in linux os.

I have google on internet, There were being saying the convert the code to .net CORE and deploy it using **mono** or **.net core**, Which i don't have any idea.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net mvc5 Project can't be deployed on Linux. However if you want to deploy it on linux, First you have to convert it into .net Core MVC Project. ASP.NET Core is available on Windows, Mac, and Linux. Follow the steps provided by the microsoft docs to convert your app into .net Core MVC and of course you have to download install .net Core.

[Migrating From ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc)