# How can I deploy an asp.net mvc 5 app into a linux machine (apache server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux

net mvc 5 web application writen in Visual Studio 2017 on a windows machine. I need to deploy this web app on a linux machine where there is an apache server.

I've tried to deploy the entire app in the /var/www/ directory but I think that I have to compile the app before somehow. I've heard that I can do that using mono or using docker. Anyone knows which one is better? I've also heard that maybe I need to make an asp.net core project because mvc is not supported on apache. I'm sure that many people have done that before so there has to be a good solution for that but I can't find it on internet. Anyone has a good and easy solution for that?
Thank you in advance.

This is what I have now with my apache configured.

[image]

Comment: Docker doesn't compile, it [composes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). For a C#/ .NET application to run on Linux you need to target a runtime that runs on Linux, with the two most popular being Mono and .NET Core. Which are you targeting?

Comment: okay I understand, which one is better mono or .NET Core? Thanks @MindSwipe

Comment: There is not definitive answer for a "Which is better?" question, some people will even defend the undefendable. Personally? I highly recommend .NET Core (especially .NET Core 3.0 Preview 5 but not necessarily for publicly accessible production apps). It's faster (and smaller) than Mono, [open-source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), and the .NET Core 3.0 is almost feature complete. Plus, the .NET Core was originally built so you can host an ASP project on Linux (hence ASP.NET)

Comment: Okay so what I have to do is a new project using asp.net core and develop my project. Then I will be able to deploy this project in linux. Is it right? Thanks @MindSwipe

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create a new project, you can port your code as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/). Also then you will be able to compile the source code to something that runs on Linux. Deploying is a whole different story. But, there is a how to from Microsoft on deploying ASP.NET Core on Linux with an Apache server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Okay Im gonna try it. Thank you!! @MindSwipe

Comment: Great, comment back with @MindSwipe if you need any more help. I'd move this to a chat, but turns out you need 20 rep to partake in chats

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494125/deploy-asp-net-mvc-in-linux